# How to get list of all files inside a folder on Google Drive using Google Drive api in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-drive-api

Hi guys i am using google-api-client gem in my app i want to get list of all images inside a folder how can i achieve it. here is my code to get list of all files on first page only.

```
require 'google/apis/drive_v2'
require 'signet/oauth_2/client'
require 'googleauth'

Drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2 # Alias the module
drive = Drive::DriveService.new
drive.authorization = authorization
files = drive.list_files
```

please let me know how i can get a list of all files inside a folder. like i have a folder named 'test_folder' and i have some files inside that folder now i want to get list of all files.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use parameter `q` with value `'#{folder_id}' an parents`

If the folder is in a shared drive, you need to set `supports_all_drives` and `include_items_from_all_drives` to `true`.

Below is my code to look for files with specified name in a specified folder in shared drive.

```ruby
query = "name = '#{file_name}' and '#{FOLDER_ID}' in parents"

response = drive_service.list_files(
    q: query,
    fields: "files(id, name)",
    supports_all_drives: true,
    include_items_from_all_drives: true
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here give this a shot.

```
service = Google::Apis::DriveV2::DriveService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize
# List the 10 most recently modified files.
response = service.list_files()
puts 'Files:'
puts 'No files found' if response.items.empty?
response.items.each do |file|
  puts "#{file.title} (#{file.id})"
end
```

for more information see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/ruby)

Comment: thanx for your suggestion but its throwing exception  unknown keyword: page_size. list_files methods list only files but i want to get all images list inside a folder please tell me how would i achieve it.

Comment: He asked for all files, this will only let him iterate in the first page.